# Retornando o resultado de uma consulta a API externa com AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-request, adonisjs

Estou consumindo uma API externa com o Request em uma aplicação feita com [adonisjs](/questions/tagged/adonisjs), a `request` é feita normalmente e está retornando o `statusCode` e `body` porém não consigo retornar para a minha API.

Quero retornar o mesmo valor que vem da API externa, no mesmo padrão sem tratamento algum:

```js
const Request = require('request');

class MyAppController {

  async index({ response, auth }) {

    Request('https://domain.com/v1/, function (error, res, body) {
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      console.log(body);
      return response.status(res.statusCode).json({ body });
    });
  }

}

module.exports = MyAppController
```

Comment: Obs: no trecho falou uma aspas no caminho da URL, porém não é esse problema

Comment: Se está faltando uma aspa conserte.

Answer (score 0):

Eu percebi que no seu código a função index está sendo chamada usando o async, mas, dentro dela, não está sendo utilizado o await. Tente fazer a seguinte alteração no seu código.

```
const Request = require('request');

class MyAppController {

  async index({ response, auth }) {
    try {
        const res = await Request("https://domain.com/v1/");
        return response.status(res.statusCode).send(res.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return response.status(500).json({err: e });
    }
}

module.exports = MyAppController
```

Uma outra forma de fazer isso é utilizando o Axios. Para instalar pelo terminal, na raiz do seu projeto, o comando é este:

```
npm install axios
```

O mesmo código ficaria assim:

```
const axios = require('axios');

class MyAppController {

  async index({ response, auth }) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://domain.com/v1/");
        return response.status(res.status).send(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
      return response.status(500).json({err: e });
    }
}

module.exports = MyAppController
```